# CSS Flex: Vertically centered items that are taller than the viewport

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So i'm using CSS flex to create vertically centered Modal popups ( `align-items: center;` ). The issue is that when the Modal is taller than the viewport (and is scrollable), the Flex prioritizes the 'centered-ness' and thus makes the top of the modal inaccessible.

Has anyone found ways around this? I could use a media query to make all Modals `flex-start` aligned, however i still want smaller modals to be vertically centered.

I had thought of trying to make the modal flex-shrink; to always fit 100% of the viewport, but it needs to scroll (and allow content to fit in further down the page) so not sure!

```
.outer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Try this `.parent{position:relative;} .largerChild{position:relative;top:50%;translate:transform(0,-50%);}`

Comment: Why don't you just set a max height for your modal of 100% and have it overflow auto?

Comment: Thank you @Pete - this has solved the issue! Still using flex, but the max height has done it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Pete for answering this:

The solution was setting `max-height: 100%;` and `overflow: auto;` (i had previously had `overflow: visible;` which caused issue.

I also found another method:

by placing the following flex properties on the 'outer outer' container (in this case, we're using ReactModal, so there's ReactModalPortal).

So we do
```.ReactModalPortal {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;

```
.innerContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

}
```
i suppose by putting `flex-start` on the parent, it always ensures the content 'begins' at the top of the window.

Answer (score -2):

Here you go

```css
.parent{
top:50px;
}
.parent,
.child {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #CCC;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #000;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically, don't use flex?

Comment: I have done a lot of stuff in html/css and never really found the need to work with flex. It can be useful in some cases, but this just works and it's clean solid solution IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your help Adam! But curious - does this solve the problem of the 'centeredness' making the tall Modals inaccessible on small-height devices? I have tried applying these properties instead of flex and it's the same result... tall modals are indeed centered, but the top area is inaccessible

Comment: Without additional margin applied with conditinal styling, there probably is not a way around it and it kind of makes sense, that it behaves that way.